# Why binary search is returning -1

Tags: java, sorting, binary-search

I am working on a small program:

```
public static void main( String args[])
    {
        String[] places = {"Bangalore","Pune","San Francisco","New York City"};
        Arrays.sort(places, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o2.compareTo(o1);
        }
    });
        System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(places, "New York City"));
    }
```

This program is printing -1, but I have "New York City" in my array then why the result is negative in this case?

Comment: You sorted the places in the reversed (descending) order.

Comment: Gotta use the same comparator used to sort them.

Comment: sorting order decides the binary search output?

Comment: You sorted the array in decreasing order, and `Arrays.binarySerch` uses by default increasing comparator. Hence, it is wrong.

Comment: An array doesn't retain the last comparator you used to sort it so a binarySearch has no way of knowing you intended anything other than increasing natural order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, `Arrays.binarySearch` assumes that the items in the array are already sorted in their natural order.  The binary search algorithm doesn't work if it's not sorted this way.

Your `Comparator` is sorting the reverse of the natural order, so the algorithm can't find New York City.

But there is an [overload of `binarySearch` that takes a `Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(T%5B%5D,T,java.util.Comparator)), so that the algorithm can assume that it's sorted the same way that the `Comparator` defines the order.

> The array must be sorted into ascending order according to the specified comparator (as by the `sort(T[], Comparator) method)` prior to making this call.

Reuse your `Comparator` in your `binarySearch` call.

```
String[] places = {"Bangalore","Pune","San Francisco","New York City"};

Comparator<String> c = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o2.compareTo(o1);
    }
};
Arrays.sort(places, c);
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(places, "New York City", c));
```

Then you'll get the correct output of `2`.

Answer (score 1):

When using a binary search, the array of data objects being searched must be in order according to the comparator being used for the search.

In your example, the cities are not in any particular order, so the search will not work.

Your comparator sorts in *reverse* alphabetical order, so the array must also be in reverse alphabetical order.

Comment: Is it just I reversed the sorting order made the binarysearch to return -1 always?

Answer (score 0):

The comparator is sorting in reverse alphabetical order. Binary Search needs the array to be sorted in ascending form.

The order of your comparator is wrong. Try:

```
String[] places = {"Bangalore","Pune","San Francisco","New York City"};
        Arrays.sort(places, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
        System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(places, "New York City"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Arrays.binarySearch** needs the array to sorted in **ascending** order,But in your case you are making it **descending**.If you change your compare function with the below,It will sort in **ascending** order

```
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
     return o1.compareTo(o2);
}
```

So if you sort it in **ascending** order, It will work

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an IDE, place a breakpoint in the Arrays.binarySearch method. Your array begins as

```
String[] places = {"Bangalore","Pune","San Francisco","New York City"};
```

but after sorting it becomes:

```
String[] places = {"San Francisco","Pune","New York City","Bangalore"};
```

so when you are using binary search, it first looks at "Pune" and then "San Francisco" because of the nature of binary search looking through only half of the "tree". Like others have said, try changing the order for your comparator, or try another searching algorithm.